# beautifulsoup CSS Select - find a tag in which a particular attribute (style for ex) is not present

Tags: python, css, selector, beautifulsoup

My first here on SO. Thanks for helping us noobs for so long. Coming straight to point:

**Scenario:**
  I am working on an existing program that is reading the CSS selector as a string from a configuration file to make the program dynamic and able to scrap any site by just changing the configuration value of CSS selector.

**Problem:**
I am trying to scrape a site which is rendering items as one of the 2 options below:

Option1:

```
.........
<div class="price">
  <span class="price" style="color:red;margin-right:0.1in">
    <del>$299</del>
  </span>
  <span class="price">
    $195
  </span> 
</div>

soup = soup.select("span.price") - this doesn't work as I need second span tag or last span tag :(
```

Option2:

```
.........
<div class="price">
  <span class="price">
    $199
  </span>
</div>

soup = soup.select("span.price") - this works great!
```

**Question:**
In both the above options I want to be able to get the last span tag ($195 or $199) and don't care about the $299. Basically I just want to extract the final sale price and not the original price.

So the 2 ways I know as of now are:

1) Always get the last span tag
 2) Always get the span tag which doesn't have style attribute

Now, I know the **not operator**, **last-of-type** are not present in bs4 (only **nth-of-type** is available) so I am stuck here. Any suggestions are helpful.

**Edit:** - Since this is an existing program, I cant use soup.find_all() or any other method apart from soup.select(). Sorry :(

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what do you need exactly but you can use display none for del 
{{{   span del { display:none; )

Comment: This book says last-of-type is available: https://books.google.nl/books?id=mEu7DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=bootstrap+4+last-of-type&source=bl&ots=zUmAMxCMG-&sig=kCjR8TivvajvtMlf-gOE5lABA2w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUuMrdlJLUAhWOY1AKHQT1AvIQ6AEIVTAH#v=onepage&q=bootstrap%204%20last-of-type&f=false

Comment: can you share url ? else try soup.select("span.price", {'style':None})

Comment: @YahyaEssam - Not sure if I understand this, could you please elaborate more. Since I don't own that website I cant change their code.

Comment: @Gerard - I think that book is talking about bootstrap 4 I meant beautifulsoup 4. Sorry for the name confusion

Comment: @gahan - Thanks for trying, this doesn't seem to work. Since the program is calling soup.select(<some string from config>) I only have the luxury of passing one string parameter. Sorry if this was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the span tag without the style attribute:

```
prices = soup.select('span.price')
no_style = [price for price in prices if 'style' not in price.attrs]
>> [<span class="price">$199</span>]
```

Comment: Thanks Gil. However since I am  working on an existing program which is just calling soup.select method hence couldn't use this way without overhauling the full program

Comment: OK, I've edited the code to use the soup.select method.  It still should work.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks again Gil. I should have mentioned that I only have the luxury of using one string which is to be passed in soup.select() method. If I were to add any additional code to this program then I need to go for full rounds of testing and I might as well make this program more flexible on a generic basis then.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good time to use a function. In this case BeautifulSoup gives `span_with_style` each tag and the function tests whether the tag's `name` is `span` and it has the attribute `style`. If this is true then BeautifulSoup appends the tag to its list of results.

```
HTML = '''\
<div class='price'>
    <span class='price' style='color: red; margin-right: 0.1in'>
        <del>$299</del>
    </span>
    <span class='price'>
        $195
    </span>
</div>'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='span' and tag.has_attr('style')):
    print (item)
```

Comment: Thanks Bill. That's a neat solution however since I am changing an existing program which is only calling soup.select(<some string from config>) I can't call the function without overhauling the entire program :(

Comment: Have a look now. --

Answer (score 0):

The code inside the select function needs to change to:

```
def select(soup, the_variable_you_pass):
    soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'price'}).find_all(the_variable_you_pass)[-1]
```